# Create recursive function argument list from one value and a size

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17, fold-expression

My intent is to create a function argument list of size n so I can pass it to a helper that uses a fold expression to recursively multiply the values together.

I'm a little stuck on how to make the argument list to pass to the helper.
Is there a way to create a function argument list without a pack expression?
Perhaps by creating an array or tuple?

Here's what I've come up with so far.

```
template<typename T, typename N>
T SmoothStart(const T& t, const N& n) {
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<N>, "templatized SmoothStart requires type of N to be integral.");
    static_assert(n >= 0, "templatized SmoothStart requires value of N to be non-negative.");

    if constexpr (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if constexpr (n == 1) {
        return t;
    }
    return SmoothStart_helper((t, ...)); //<-- obviously this doesn't work but it would be awesome to have!
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T SmoothStart_helper(Args&&... args) {
    return (args * ...);
}
```

Comment: What is `t`? Do you just want `n` copies of `t`?

Comment: @Justin Yes, exactly. Say n is 5 I want an argument list composed of `SmoothStart_helper(t,t,t,t,t)`

Comment: The problem I see is that `n` is a run time value but, for this sort of solutions, you need to know it compile time. If you can make `n` a template `std::size_t` value, all goes simpler.

Comment: You might rename `SmoothStart` to `Power<std::size_t N, typename T>(const T&t)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 SmoothStart is part of the easing function family (smoothstep is also one), the domain is different from Power and it would be misleading to call it Power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, `n` must be known at compile-time if you want to use a fold expression. If you move that to a template parameter, the easiest way to get a parameter pack of a size `N` is with [`std::make_index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence):

```
// The helper has to be first so that the compiler can find SmoothStart_helper().
template<typename T, std::size_t... Is>
T SmoothStart_helper(const T& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    // You were taking t by value here; I think you might want to still
    // take it by reference

    // Use the comma operator to simply discard the current index and instead
    // yield t. The cast to void is to silence a compiler warning about
    // Is being unused
    return (((void) Is, t) * ...);
}

template<std::size_t N, typename T>
T SmoothStart(const T& t) {
    // std::size_t is unsigned, so no need to check for N >= 0.
    // We also don't need to special case when N == 1. The fold
    // expression handles that case and just returns t
    return SmoothStart_helper(t, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

You can then use it like so: `SmoothStart<N>(myThing);`.

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/HQw9Lo)